# How to cache a (timestamped) value of returned by Inno Setup scripted constant?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup to create backups in a system.
I've created a function that allows me to generate a folder with a timestamp, but that timestamp keeps on changing every time I run a command during the "setup".
The first command I run will put the files in folder: `D:\Onderhoud\Onderhoud 2023\SystemA-20231231-2350\`
The second command (within that same setup) will put the files in folder: `D:\Onderhoud\Onderhoud 2023\SystemA-20231231-2352\`
The third command in: `D:\Onderhoud\Onderhoud 2023\SystemA-20231231-2359\`
etc. etc.
I would like to generate one single variable that will be used during the setup, so from the moment setup starts it'll put the files in `D:\Onderhoud\Onderhoud 2023\SystemA-20231231-2350\`

My function is very basic and looks like:

```pascal
function InspectieOnderhoudDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  result :=
    'Onderhoud ' + GetDateTimeString('yyyy', '-', ':') +
    '\SystemA-' + GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd-hhmm', '-', ':');
end;
```

The commands I run in the `[Run]` section are:

```
Filename: "robocopy.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/MIR C:\PROGRAMNAME\ ""{app}\{code:InspectieOnderhoudDir}\PROGRAMNAME_Backup\ """; \
    Flags: runhidden; Components: Backup

; BackupNetworkSettings (added 25-10-2022)
Filename: "{cmd}"; \
    Parameters: "/c ""mkdir -p ""{app}\{code:InspectieOnderhoudDir}\Netwerk Instellingen\ """; \
    Flags: runhidden; Components: Backup
Filename: "{cmd}"; \
    Parameters: "/c ""netsh.exe -c interface dump > ""{app}\{code:InspectieOnderhoudDir}\Netwerk Instellingen\INEX\netsh.txt """; \
    Components: Backup\BackupNetworkSetting
```

etc. etc.

What do I need to change so my setup will generate a timestamped folder that remains the same during that setup, but changes when I start a new setup?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to generate the value on the first call only and cache it:

```pascal
var
  OnderhoudDir: string;

function InspectieOnderhoudDir(Param: string): string;
begin
  if OnderhoudDir = '' then
  begin
    OnderhoudDir :=
      'Onderhoud ' + GetDateTimeString('yyyy', '-', ':') + '\SystemA-' +
      GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd-hhmm', '-', ':');
    Log(Format('Generated folder: %s', [OnderhoudDir]));
  end;

  Result := OnderhoudDir;
end;
```

---

More deterministic approach is to generate the value in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup):

```pascal
var
  OnderhoudDir: string;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  OnderhoudDir :=
    'Onderhoud ' + GetDateTimeString('yyyy', '-', ':') + '\SystemA-' +
    GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd-hhmm', '-', ':');
  Log(Format('Generated folder: %s', [OnderhoudDir]));
  Result := True;
end;

function InspectieOnderhoudDir(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := OnderhoudDir;
end;
```